# cloudinary download PDF

Tags: cloudinary, django-uploads

I have a django app and I let my users upload files to a Cloudinary account I set-up. I am no trying to allow users to download those files back by clicking on link (that supposedly should trigger a download from Cloudinary).

I am failing to achive this, especially for PDFs.

ANy help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a recent update to our security policies, we've restricted the ability of new free accounts to deliver PDFs and Archive files like .zip or .rar. It's possible to upload and manage those files, and you can download them using our Media Library, but a restriction applies to deliver them publicly and you'll see an HTTP 401 error in that case.

For PDFs that are uploaded as resource_type: 'image', it's possible to use those PDFs with our transformations features, so you can convert the PDFs to another image format and deliver them that way, such as by using the page transformation (pg_ in URLs) and setting the extension to an image format like jpg: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/pg_1/multi_page_pdf.jpg

We can control and lift this restriction from specific accounts, but we also need to ensure that no malicious files are distributed through our service.

Open a ticket at https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new so that we can lift the restriction.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot!